# Radare2 "pd" vs "pda"

Tags: python, malware, opcode, radare2

I am currently trying to extract all opcodes from PE files. I am wondering what the difference between Radare2's "pd" command which "disassemble N bytes" and the "pda" command which "disassemble all possible opcodes (byte per byte)". Which command should I use to find all the opcodes from a PE file?

Comment: Are you looking to extract the assembly `xor eax, eax`, the bytes `31 c0`, the opcode `31`, or maybe just the instruction `xor`?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by *all* opcodes. x86<sup>1</sup> is a CISC architecture. Not all instructions have the same size.

Consider the following byte sequence:

```
55 48 89 e5
```

which corresponds to

```
    55  push rbp
4889e5  mov rbp, rsp
```

in x86 64bit. And that's what you get with `pd` (if you start at the beginning). However, there is an other opcode hidden in this byte sequence, namely `89 e5` which is `mov ebp, esp`. `pdA` will also reveal this.

```
0     55  push rbp
1 4889e5  mov rbp, rsp
2   89e5  mov ebp, esp
3     e5  <invalid>
```

In `pdA` r2 always increments by a byte an tries to disassemble an opcode.

---

<sup>1</sup> Since you want to analyze PEs I assume you use x86_64